# How to subscribe for the Taskpane close event

Tags: office-js, office-addins

Is there any event to identify when the task pane is getting closed using office JS? Basically i need to clear the cookies and the session storage

Comment: May be this is a workaround. Instead of looking for that event. You may try clearing `on init` of add-in.  I am following this approach and it works really well

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your post, so far we don't provide the taskpane close event, in your scenario, you could clean the cookies and storage in Office.onReady();